# I have this super long mysql that updates a column in a table for a month is there any way to simpfy it?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

```
CREATE table 'table'(
      date_received date,
      received_total int

);


INSERT INTO 'table'
select

    date_format(date_received,'%Y/%m/%d') as  date_received,
    count(req_id)  as received_total


from 'table2'
where date_received is not null
  and date_received  >= (date_format('2022-10-03','%Y/%m/%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
  and dept_name = 'aClientName'
group by date_format(date_received,'%Y/%m/%d')

order by date_received desc

ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD COLUMN expected_avg int AFTER received_total;


;

UPDATE 'table' set expected_avg = (

    select
        round(count(req_id) / 6) as expected_avg
    from 'table2'
    where date_received  is not null
      and date_received  >= ('2022-09-03' - INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
      and date_received <= '2022-09-03'
      and dayofweek(date_received) = dayofweek('2022-09-03')
      and dept_name = 'aClientName'

)
where date_received = '2022-09-03'

UPDATE 'table' set expected_avg = (

    select
        round(count(req_id) / 6) as expected_avg
    from 'table2'
    where date_received  is not null
      and date_received  >= ('2022-09-04' - INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
      and date_received <= '2022-09-04'
      and dayofweek(date_received) = dayofweek('2022-09-03')
      and dept_name = 'aClientName'

)
where date_received = '2022-09-04'
```

The query pulls data from a premade table, creates another table with a blank column then updates the column for a month. If someone can help me simplify the updating of the column part id be very grateful. The query should work for the current month or any given month.

Comment: Well you can throw away the first UPDATE after the ALTER, as the second UPDATE will overwrite the value anyway

Comment: I would also suggest you can throw away the whole lot and just run a query to calc the values from the existing table, all this table creation etc etc is a complete waste of time